# how to filter by schema property in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `group` object, which is included an `members` property. The `members` property is an array of objects. That object is having following properties.

```
{"id" : "1", "status" : 1}
```

My requirement is to get the list of users, who are having status `1`, of a given `group` object (by a given id).

This is possible to do, with a simple get by ID query and a `foreach`. But want to know, is there any advance query to do this.

My overall Group object as follows.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  user_id:{
    type : Schema.ObjectId,
    ref : 'User',
    default : null
  },
  status:{
    type : Number,
    default : null /* 1 - pending | 2 - rejected | 3 - accepted*/
  },
});

var GroupSchema = new Schema({
  type:{
    type : Number,
    default : 1 /* 1 - group | 2 - community*/
  },
  name:{
    type:String,
    default:null
  },
  members:[UserSchema]

},{collection:"groups"});
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Did you mean for a given _group_ object instead of _post_ object?

Comment: Instead of giving the Schema definition, it'd be good to share few sample documents and expected output such that it would be easy to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @chridam `group` object. Edited the question.

Comment: @suzo My expected result is an array of members, who are having status one.

Comment: Can you check my answer and tell me if that is what you are expecting ?

Comment: I noticed your answer. Thank you for answering. But your query returns a group Collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework to filter the documents in the groups collection by the given group id and the members array status field. This will be your initial pipeline stage which is **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator-driven.

The next pipeline step should be the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operator which selects a subset of the members array based on a given condition. This is necessary since the previous pipeline only filters at document level, not at array/field level.

Once you get the filtered array you can then apply the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** function as means to "populate" your members list. However, since `localField` is an array and you want to match the elements inside it against a `foreignField` which is a single element, you'll need to **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** the array as one stage of the aggregation pipeline before applying the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator.

The following example demonstrates how you can apply all the above steps in your case:

```
Group.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "_id": groupId,
            "members.status": 1         
        } 
    },
    {
        "$filter": {
            "input": "$members",
            "as": "member",
            "cond": { "$eq": ["$$member.status", 1] }
        }
    }
    { "$unwind": "$members" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users"
            "localField": "members.user_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "member"
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, results) { 
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
});
```

The results will contain a list of documents which have both the group and user attributes.

---

If your MongoDB version does not support the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** and **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operators introduced in version 3.2. X and newer, then consider using the **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** and **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator combo to filter the array elements in a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline.

The **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator in essence creates a new array field that holds values as a result of the evaluated logic in a subexpression to each element of an array. The **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** operator then returns a set with elements that appear in the first set but not in the second set; i.e. performs a relative complement of the second set relative to the first. In this case it will return the final members array that has elements not related to the parent documents via the `status` property.

Execute the aggregate operation after the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline step and since the documents returned are plain javascript objects, not [Mongoose Documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js) (any shape of document can be returned), you need to cast the results to [Mongoose Documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js) so that you can use populate function on the field with the results.

The following example demonstrates the above workaround:

```
Group.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "_id": groupId,
            "members.status": 1         
        } 
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "type": 1, "name": 1,
            "members": {
                "$setDifference": [
                    {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$members",
                            "as": "member",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": [
                                    { "$eq": [ "$$member.status", 1 ] },
                                    "$$member",
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, result) { 
    if (err) throw err;
    var docs = result.map(function(doc) { return new Group(doc) });
    Group.populate(docs, { "path": "members" }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results, undefined, 4 ));
        res.json(results);
    });
});
```

Comment: @sacDahal It works by performing a "left outer join" to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing. The `$lookup` stage does an equality match between a field from the input documents with a field from the documents of the "joined" collection. Sometimes `$lookup` can be misused to treat MongoDB like a relational database but developers should know when its use is appropriate, and when it’s an anti-pattern.

Comment: looks like my mongoDB version is not compatible with `$filter` pipeline stage. Is there other possible  stage we can use to replace `$filter` .

Comment: What's your MongoDB and Mongoose version?

Comment: @ErangaKapukotuwa I've added a workaround, give that a go and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your collection name is `groups`, you can query like this :

```
db.groups.find({"members.status":1}, {"members":1});
```

This will fetch all the users that has status 1. If you want to query based on a specific user_id (assuming user id as "1A" here) , you can add in the object like this :

```
db.groups.find({"members.status":1, "members.user_id":"1A"}, {"members":1});
```